# All of your doubt will suddenly go away / goes away?

Tags: modal-verbs

"All of your doubt will suddenly go away when..."

"All of your doubt will suddenly goes away when..."

Go away or goes away?
Which sentence is grammatically right?

Answer (score 1):

"All of your doubt will suddenly go away" is correct because *will go* is the future tense of the verb *to go*. You could use the present tense *goes*, but without the *will*, i.e. "All of your doubt suddenly goes away when... your question is answered on StackExchange."

Comment: These questions are often easier to understand when you simplify the sentence by removing adjectives and adverbs and replacing nouns with simple pronouns. So simplify the first sentence to "It will go away"--this is correct. Simplify the second to "It will goes away"--this is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use "All of your doubt will suddenly go away when...". *Go* is a verb used with a plural subject (which 'all of your doubt' is), while *goes* is only used when you have a singular subject (like *The dog **goes** to the store*)

Comment: This is really the same question as your "what would he likes to eat"

Answer (score 0):

After modal verbs you have infinitive present or infinitive perfect.

can/could + do/have done

may/might  + do/have done

must/--- + do/have done - must has no past form, only in sub-clauses a past tense of must can occur in literature

shall/should + do/have done

will/would + do/ have done

Comment: Or infinitive progressive.

Comment: Of  course,  there are passive infinitives, too, and  progressive forms.  For the whole table of infiniitive forms there are grammars.